# Swift: Weakly reference function as closure?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, closures, strong-reference-cycle

In Swift, I'm currently facing the issue where I need to often wrap `functions` in `closures` in order to prevent strong reference cycles when passing on a class's function as a closure parameter. For example, in the scenario below:

```
class A {
    var foo: () -> Void
}

class B {

    private let a: A

    init() {
        self.a = A()
        a.foo = { [weak self] in self?.foo() } // <- Can this be simplified, while still avoiding strong reference cycles?
    }

    private func foo() {}

}
```

Having to always type `{ [weak self] in self?.myFunc() }` is not nice, as it opens the door people accidentally introducing memory leaks as they forgot to wrap `myFunc` in a closure. Is there an easier/more foolproof way that similar behavior can be achieved?

-- Edit

If no easier way exists, I will likely open up a feature request @ Apple for syntax that looks something like:

```
init() {
    self.a = A()
    a.foo = weak foo
}
```

where `a.foo = weak foo` is equivalent to `a.foo = { [weak self] in self?.foo() }`

Or, when dealing with functions that aren't owned by `self`:

```
let b = B()
let a = A()
a.foo = weak b.foo
```

where `a.foo = weak b.foo` is equivalent to `a.foo = { [weak b] in b?.foo() }`

**Note: I am not proposing to make closures themselves weakly referencable. I'm simply proposing that `weak b.foo` is compiled identically to `{ [weak b] in b?.foo() }`**

Comment: If you want to use an instance method of Class B to set the foo property of A, as far as I know, this is the only way to do it without causing memory leaks.  There is a discussion going on though to make closure properties weak https://forums.swift.org/t/weak-closure-reference/16085

Comment: @AnirudhBandi what is proposed in that topic is slightly different though. In that discussion, they propose to make closures a reference-type, which I do not propose. What I propose, is that some syntax sugar is introduced so that `a.foo = weak b.foo` is compiled equivalently to `a.foo = { [weak b] in b?.foo() }`. The difference is that in the discussion you are pointing to, they propose to store the closure as a whole weakly. I'm proposing to still box the closure, but hide that from the programmer.

Comment: I have found this discussion on Swift Forums, but no solution for your problem. https://forums.swift.org/t/implicit-retain-cycle/15238/10